# CMake - Including a file in a library without exposing it to other projects

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries

I'm trying to learn CMake and I've run into a little hiccup. I have a library with a structure somewhat like this:

```
LibProj
| include
| | public1.h
| | public2.h
| library
| | public1.cpp
| | public2.cpp
```

Now, let's say I want a .h file that may or may not be associated with a .cpp file that I want to only be used by the files within the library. That is, I don't want it exposed to projects that use the library. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical solution is to move the internal stuff to another directory:

```
LibProj
| include
| | public1.h
| internal
| | private1.h
```

And then only add the `internal` folder as an include directory in your library and make sure it is not copied at [install time](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3ainstall). In general it is not possible to allow including one header file from a directory but disallow another. Most (if not all) compilers only allow to specify include directories, not singular include files.